# numberOfRowsInSection for Objects

Tags: ios, nsarray

I have a code that I'm writing for testing.

On it I'll create Object Instances where the name of it will be the Rows.

Example: Name Lucille: will stack up together an just show "Frango" and "Beef Brisket";

I can't figure out how to do 3 things:

1. Organize the Rows in alphabetical order;
2. Show the correct amount of cells per rows;
3. Show only the respective cells for the rows that they belong(name being the category);

Here is what I have so far:

```
#import "EAMasterViewController.h"

#import "EADetailViewController.h"
#import "review.h"
#import "CelulaTableViewCell.h"

@interface EAMasterViewController () {
    NSMutableArray *_objects;
    NSMutableArray *secoes;
    NSMutableArray *dicrows;
    NSMutableDictionary *nn;

}
@end

@implementation EAMasterViewController

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    //Bar "+"  Button
    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;


    _tabela = [NSMutableArray array];
    [_tabela addObject:[review newReviewWithName:@"Luccille" dish:@"Frango" rating:@"3"]];
    [_tabela addObject:[review newReviewWithName:@"In-n-Out" dish:@"Camarão grelhado" rating:@"5"]];
    [_tabela addObject:[review newReviewWithName:@"Azul Tequila" dish:@"Frango grelhado" rating:@"1"]];
    [_tabela addObject:[review newReviewWithName:@"Charcoal" dish:@"Cheese Burguer" rating:@"4"]];
    [_tabela addObject:[review newReviewWithName:@"Luccille" dish:@"Beef Brisket" rating:@"2"]];
    [_tabela addObject:[review newReviewWithName:@"In-n-Out" dish:@"double-double" rating:@"1"]];
    [_tabela addObject:[review newReviewWithName:@"Azul Tequila" dish:@"Chips" rating:@"5"]];
    [_tabela addObject:[review newReviewWithName:@"Azul Tequila" dish:@"Dips" rating:@"4"]];
    [_tabela addObject:[review newReviewWithName:@"Mooses" dish:@"Dips" rating:@"4"]];
    [_tabela addObject:[review newReviewWithName:@"In-n-Out" dish:@"Cheese Burguer" rating:@"5"]];



    self.arraySections;

}


- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{
    if (!_objects) {
        _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [_objects insertObject:[NSDate date] atIndex:0];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (void) arraySections{
    secoes = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    int c, count = 0, d;

    for(c=0;c<_tabela.count;c++){

        for(d=0;d<count;d++)
        {
            review *temp1 = _tabela[(c)];

            if ([temp1.restaurant isEqualToString:secoes[(d)]])
               break;
        }
        if (d == count)
        {
            review *temp = _tabela[(c)];
            secoes[(count)] = temp.restaurant;
            count++;
        }
    }



    ///  **** Nuber of rows in Section

    dicrows = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    nn = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    NSMutableArray *rows = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:secoes];

    NSLog(@"%@",rows);

    for (int i = 0; i<rows.count; i++) {
        NSString *temp = rows[(i)];
        NSInteger x = 0;
        for (int j =0; j<_tabela.count; j++) {
            review *temp1 = _tabela[(j)];
            //            NSLog(@"tabela rest em J é: %@",temp1.restaurant);
            if ([temp isEqualToString:temp1.restaurant]) {
                x++;
            }

        }

        [dicrows addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:temp, @"restaurant",
                                                                            [NSNumber numberWithInt:x], @"quantidade", nil]];
        [nn setObject:temp forKey:@"restaurant"];
        [nn setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:x] forKey:@"quantidade"];
    }

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [secoes count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        return [secoes objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    NSLog(@"oi");
    return ??????????????;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    CelulaTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    review *reviews = _tabela[indexPath.row];
    cell.nome_restaurante.text = reviews.restaurant;
    cell.nome_rating.text = reviews.rating;
    cell.nome_dish.text = reviews.dish;


    return cell;
}

@end
```

And this is the review.m

```
#import "review.h"

@implementation review



+(review *)newReviewWithName:(NSString *)restaurant
                        dish:(NSString *)dish
                      rating:(NSString *)rating{

    review *Review = [[review alloc]init];
    Review.restaurant = restaurant;
    Review.dish = dish;
    Review.rating = rating;
    return Review;
}


@end
```

I'd appreciate any help.  I've seen several places where people use NSDictionary for the rows and sections but I really want to try to make it work with casting Objects on the Class review.m.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Review.h"

@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
@property (nonatomic,  retain) NSMutableDictionary *dict;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (NSMutableDictionary *)dict
{
    if(!_dict) {
        _dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
    return _dict;
}

//- (void)dealloc
//{
//    [_dict release];
//    [super dealloc];
//}

- (void)addReview:(Review *)review
{
    if(review.restaurant) {

        NSMutableArray *arr = self.dict[review.restaurant];
        if(!arr) {
            arr = [NSMutableArray array];
            [self.dict setObject:arr forKey:review.restaurant];
        }

        [arr addObject:review];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray array];
    [arr addObject:[Review reviewWithRestaurant:@"Luccille" dish:@"Frango" rating:@"3"]];
    [arr addObject:[Review reviewWithRestaurant:@"In-n-Out" dish:@"Camarão grelhado" rating:@"5"]];
    [arr addObject:[Review reviewWithRestaurant:@"Azul Tequila" dish:@"Frango grelhado" rating:@"1"]];
    [arr addObject:[Review reviewWithRestaurant:@"Charcoal" dish:@"Cheese Burguer" rating:@"4"]];
    [arr addObject:[Review reviewWithRestaurant:@"Luccille" dish:@"Beef Brisket" rating:@"2"]];
    [arr addObject:[Review reviewWithRestaurant:@"In-n-Out" dish:@"double-double" rating:@"1"]];
    [arr addObject:[Review reviewWithRestaurant:@"Azul Tequila" dish:@"Chips" rating:@"5"]];
    [arr addObject:[Review reviewWithRestaurant:@"Azul Tequila" dish:@"Dips" rating:@"4"]];
    [arr addObject:[Review reviewWithRestaurant:@"Mooses" dish:@"Dips" rating:@"4"]];
    [arr addObject:[Review reviewWithRestaurant:@"In-n-Out" dish:@"Cheese Burguer" rating:@"5"]];

    [arr sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        Review *review1 = (Review *)obj1;
        Review *review2 = (Review *)obj2;

        NSComparisonResult result = [review1.restaurant compare:review2.restaurant];
        if(result == NSOrderedSame) {
            result = [review1.dish compare:review2.dish];
        }
        return result;
    }];

    [arr enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        [self addReview:obj];
    }];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return self.dict.allKeys.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id key = self.dict.allKeys[section];
    NSArray *arr = self.dict[key];
    return arr.count;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.dict.allKeys[section];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
//        [cell autorelease];
    }

    id key = self.dict.allKeys[indexPath.section];
    NSArray *arr = self.dict[key];
    Review *review = arr[indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ / %@ / %@", review.restaurant, review.dish, review.rating];
    return cell;
}

@end
```

You may use this code for your testing. And there is one thing you should know that it's recommendable to use uppercase at the first letter of a class name.
Lastly, this code is for ARC project. if you use ARC project, just remove the comments.